# ReactJS dangerouslySetStyle?

Tags: reactjs

I am using ReactJS and am aware of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but I want to be able to set an element's `style` attribute to a raw string. I've searched and had a look through the React source but I can't find anything.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'd like to know roughly the reason why are you doing this. Because it goes against ReactJS philosophy. Please keep in mind that ReactJS uses shadow DOM to get diffs which are applied to the actual DOM. InnerHTML could cause vulnerability and performance issues.

Comment: @MichaelCzolko It is because some style is coming from a JSON feed and needs to be merged with the other style attributes before being rendered. I don't believe this goes against the React philosophy at all - it's no different than creating the style using the normal methods.

Answer (score 9):

You have to manually set the attribute on the dom node to do this.  The simplest way would be with a wrapper component:

```js
<CustomAttribute tag="div" dangerouslySetAttributes={{style: 'color:red'}}>
  red text
</CustomAttribute>
```

And the actual component

```js
var DSA = 'dangerouslySetAttributes';
var CustomAttribute = React.createClass({
  setAttributes: function(oldAttrs, attrs){
    var el = this.getDOMNode();
    Object.keys(attrs).forEach(function(key){
      if (oldAttrs[key] !== attrs[key]) 
        el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
    });
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){ 
    this.setAttributes({}, this.props[DSA]);
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps){ 
    this.setAttributes(this.props[DSA], nextProps[DSA]);
  },
  render: function(){
    var Tag = this.props.tag || 'div';
    return <Tag>{this.props.children}</Tag>
  },
});
```

<sub>*not tested</sub>

Comment: Yes I would think that would work. In my case I need to set the style from a string in Javascript as it is coming from an Ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set the entire markup, including styles, in dangerouslySetInnerHTML, like such:

```
var markup = "<div style='"+dynamicStyleString+"'>Content</div>"

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: markup}}></div>
```

That should get the job done

Answer (score 0):

I looked more thoroughly through the React source and in **/src/vendor/core/camelize.js** I found this:

```
/**
 * Copyright 2013-2014, Facebook, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 *
 * @providesModule camelize
 * @typechecks
 */

var _hyphenPattern = /-(.)/g;

/**
 * Camelcases a hyphenated string, for example:
 *
 *   > camelize('background-color')
 *   < "backgroundColor"
 *
 * @param {string} string
 * @return {string}
 */
function camelize(string) {
  return string.replace(_hyphenPattern, function(_, character) {
    return character.toUpperCase();
  });
}

module.exports = camelize;
```

So it is a little inefficient in that it turns a hypenated style attribute into camel case and then React turns it back again but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Its simple to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML:
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.value}}></div>

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

It will work same as like normal html/JS:

 <div id="name"></div>
 <script>
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = "test test";
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not using [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)? When you receive new state from your resource then React will take care of rendering the correct style attributes.

Basically the code is:

```
classNames({
'random-string': condition ? true : false
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the DV, but as much as I disagree with what he's trying to do/ask here, classnames are not a drop-in solution/replacement for trying to merge arbitrary styles.  Should he find a way to turn it into a stylesheet or something before merging in?  Probably... till then, this solution won't help.

Comment: Yeh I think i didn't ready the OP question properly before answering :)